Is it possible to find out what AMM a VersionedTransaction used?
So I get a VersionedTransaction which represents a transaction someone made. I want to make a trade in the same Raydium AMM. Currently I pull the token from the transaction and lookup the largest pool. But I want the same pool that they used.
How would I find this out?

your question is a little bit vague. could you provide further clarification, what's the tx, how are you looking up the largest pool.
